# Is there better method than this one to solve quadratic diophantine equations?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, alternative-proof

Say we have the quadratic Diophantine equation :

$4x^2+9y^2=100$

I'm not really sure what the usual method to find integer solutions to these equations are , but one way I thought of was the following :

we know $4x^2\geq 0 \Rightarrow 9y^2 \leq 100 \Rightarrow y^2\leq 11.111 \Rightarrow -3.333 \geq y \leq 3.333$, so we know $y=-3,-2,-1,0,1,2$ or $3$.

We must also have the condition that $x^2=\tfrac{100-9y^2}{4}$ is an integer, and the square of an integer.

giving

$y=0, x=5$

$y=0, x=-5$

$y=2, x=4$

$y=2, x=-4$

$y=-2, x=4$

$y=-2, x=-4$

these pairs making up the set of integer solutions.

My questions are , firstly is this an okay method ? Secondly is there a better method ? After all if we had a very large number on the R.H.S. this trial and error method would be very impractical , I feel there must certainly be a more efficient one.

Edit: Particularly I would like to know is there a better method than this one for the general quadratic Diophantine equation , $ax^2+by^2=c$

Comment: It's $(2x)^2+(3y)^2=100$, so if you know all the ways to represent $100$ as a sum of two squares, you can solve this problem.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown is there a general method for finding the intger solutions equations of the form $ax^+by^2=c$ though ?

Comment: There is a method published by Muskat and Williams. Let me find a link.

Comment: As far as I know, the only way to find all solutions of $x^2+y^2=n$ is first to factorise $n$ into primes.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1990-55-191/S0025-5718-1990-1023762-3/S0025-5718-1990-1023762-3.pdf   Just a caution, the examples in the article do not illustrate some of the possible problems

Comment: @WillJagy Great , thank you :)

Comment: you can write $y=x+\alpha$, then substitute $y^2$ by $(x+\alpha)^2$ to get a quadratic equation in $x$ whose discriminant will depend on the value of $\alpha$. So you would try different values until you get one that makes the discriminant a square.

Comment: if you do the algebra, you will end up with the following quadratic. $13x^2+18x\alpha$+$9\alpha^2-100=0$. The discriminant is given by $\delta=5200-144\alpha^2$. The discriminant is a square for $\alpha=2$ or $(x,y)=(-4,-2)$ and $\alpha=5$ or $(x,y)=(-5,0)$. I didn't look for other solutions.

Comment: Quadratic diophanitne equations are NP-complete (https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17478/diophantine-equations-and-complexity-classes) so in a sense there is no good method at all for solving them (provided $P\ne NP$). But in practice https://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM does a pretty good job on reasonable-sized problems, and you can set it to show not just the answers but all the steps it uses.

Comment: Have you followed up on these links?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: @GerryMyerson sorry, I have exams in two weeks so I've been really busy. I'm working on a physics paper right now because its my first one, but 'll look at these as soo as I start number theory again. Thank you so much for your help :)